# Can I safely remove assets after uninstalling Unreal?

Tags: assets, unreal-5, asset-management

I uninstalled Unreal Engine 5.1.
I have several projects saved, some of which are using a lot of disk space. This is mostly because of downloaded assets (like Megascans).

- Is there any way I can glean from the project's file directory (`..\<ProjectName>\Content\`) whether an asset is referenced in the project itself (instead of just having been downloaded)?
- Alternatively, if I remove the contents of the different folders, will Unreal be able to re-download them once I open up the project again?

(I realize there are ways to do this while the engine is installed, but I can't find anything on the matter when I no longer am able to open projects.)

Comment: Would it not be simply easier to just reinstall UE and handle it properly from there? Future you will say thank you when you dont need to fix a lot of broken references in case something goes wrong

Comment: @Zibelas Very true, but the reason I uninstalled it was that the engine is so sluggish on my current system, and it will take a while to redownload. If that is the best option, I'll gladly accept it, but I'm hoping to be able to clean up files without having to go through the whole installation process again :)

Comment: Myself I think I'd buy a portable hard drive, and move these projects there until I want to use them again. Then I know I have a complete working copy, without them taking up space on my main drive.